# Windows 7 losing one of my displays after restart

Tags: windows-7, video, multiple-monitors, display-driver

I have an Intel DZ68BC motherboard with Intel HD graphics card using two monitors (on DVI and on HDMI » VGA). My friend asked me to test if his NVIDIA graphics card works well on my computer (at his it was doing some trouble), so I inserted it in my computer, installed the NVIDIA driver and it worked quite well. Then I removed it, uninstalled everything NVIDIA-related I could find and switched monitors back to my Intel card.

Since then after every system start/restart, the system sees only monitor on HDMI » VGA connector, completely ignoring the DVI monitor.

I noticed that installing the Intel video drivers causes the system to recognize the second monitor if I don't immediately reboot. After a reboot, the system recognizes only the HDMI » VGA monitor.

I also tried starting in safe-mode and using DriveSweeper to remove the remains of NVIDIA drivers. While it seems that some drivers were removed, the situation didn't change. Now I am out of ideas and I really wouldn't like to reinstall the system (again...).

I also tried restoring the system to the state before this whole story, but it also didn't change anything.

EDIT:

I am still trying to troubleshoot this problem. The only point that I could start was driver re-instalation. I traced down the part that restores right settings to a call:

```
C:\Users\Jarek\Desktop\GFX_Win7_64_8.15.10.2696\x64\Drv64.exe -driverinf "C:\Users\Jarek\Desktop\GFX_Win7_64_8.15.10.2696\Graphics\igdlh64.inf" -flags 20 -keypath "Software\Intel\Difx64"
```

This call fixes my displays, and as workaround, I will add it for now to my autorun. I am still looking for better solution anyway...

EDIT2:

Using [DriverView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html) i made a list of currently used drivers both before and after fixing my display using above command. Then i compared logs:

- No drivers were removed by fixing command.
- Drivers added by fixing command:

  - MS Remote Access serial network driver (asyncmac.sys)
  - security processor (spsys.sys)
- Drivers that changed base address (indicates driver-reload?)

  - Canonical Display Driver (cdd.dll)
  - Intel Graphics Kernel Mode Driver (igdkmd64.sys)
  - Monitor Driver (monitor.sys)

Added drivers seem rather unrelated to the problem to me, reloaded drivers are just a cnsequence of installing new driver file so there is not much to go here... I really cannot make heads or tails out of it...

EDIT3:

I made clean install of Windows 7, and guess what? It still doesn't work... After some more googling it seems that it's most likely faulty driver - after I installed it, HDMI went down... If i didn't have additional VGA monitor, I would probably conclude that my graphic card doesn't work at all. I really wonder how did I get it working in the first place. I remember installing Windows 7 without big problems. The drivers I used before were the same as used now, and I disabled automatic updates while installing W7, in case some of them are causing trouble - without much success.

I found out that it's enough to disable and re-enable your graphic card to get it working. You can use DevCon.exe (don't use the old one that you can download directly, it's veeeery old. Please extract it from [WDDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800), from archive WDK\setuptools_x64fre_cab001.cab). After you find out right *Hardware ID* for your video card, it's best to create small script (.bat file) using `devcon restart <HwID>` and add it to logon scripts ('gpedit.msc' -> Computer configuration -> Windows settings -> Scripts).

While it's a hack, it works so well, that you won't even notice it was there. And I am avoiding constant re-installing drivers (in my old method) which is quite significant on my SSD drive I think ;)

Comment: To anybody who can close question - there is little chance for any progress here, so please close it...