# Windows "Color Management" see no monitor after video driver uninstall (Solved)

Tags: graphics-card, windows-8.1, colors, display-driver, color-profiles

I used to be able to color calilb the built-in and external monitor of my Lenovo G500 64-bit Win8.1 laptop.  Then suddenly Color Calibration of Win has error when I tried to calib the external monitor.  It seems that the Color Management of Win can not see the external monitor under "Device".

So I updated the Intel HD graphic 4000 driver with no effect.  Then I uninstalled the video card driver and re-install from scratch.  Now Color Management see no monitor at all!  :(

I wonder if there is some additional step need to run to "notify" Win 8.1 after the re-install.  I find similar issue in this thread:
[Windows 7 losing one of my displays after restart](https://superuser.com/questions/439493/windows-7-losing-one-of-my-displays-after-restart)

I also found out that I cannot adjust the brightness (either under Power Option or using the hotkey) after this re-install.

But it was beyond me to learn any useful hints.

I really don't want to re-install windows.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just did a System Restore to the point before I un-install the video driver.  After Restore, now Color Management can see my built-in monitor, just like it was before.

Comment: Then, I read about another webpage about changing the driver.  It occurred to me that the external monitor may be using the wrong driver.  (It never occurred to me at all).  So I under Device Manger, I update the driver for MONITOR, choose "Search my computer" and then choose the "Generic PnP Monitor" instead the one with "(Standard)".  Voila! Now Color Management sees the monitor under "Device".  This is so ridiculously easy.  I thought the video driver was the problem.  It actually was the MONITOR driver!!!

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me after a Windows 10 self-update.

In `Device Manager` the monitor was marked as disabled. Right clicking and pressing on `Enable` Solved it for me.

You may need to press `Update Driver Software` If it doesn't work for you right away.